# Is there a function in C which checks whether a character is a character or integer, etc?

Tags: c, c-libraries

I have a a homework, and my professor said some of the students figured out that they could check whether the characters they read in are specific ones using a function. He said it was in the string.h library, but I checked and I don't see it. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Look into the standard header [`ctype.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/ctype.h.html).

Side note, most of them are usually implemented as macros, see [Plauger](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131315099).

Comment: Thanks! New to C so I am not sure about where to access all the libraries or what all of them even are. Appreciate the link.

Answer (score 1):

The function [`isalpha`](http://www.elook.org/programming/c/isalpha.html) can help you out finding the rest of them.

```
char c;
scanf("%c", &c);
if (isalpha(c))
  printf("You entered a letter of some alphabet\n");
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the added visual plus the link.

Comment: @jørgensen is `isalpha` localized? For example if you enter an ascii-extended character like é, is `isalpha('é')` true? (I don't even know if you can do `'é'` ... XD)

Answer (score 0):

Check `isalpha` and `isdigit` functions.

Answer (score 0):

Could be [`strspn`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strspn).

> `size_t strspn(const char *s, const char *accept);`
>
> The strspn() function calculates the length of the initial segment of
>   s which consists entirely of characters in accept.